# How can i det data in 3 inner joined tables to pivot on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

i have a large query that i am building but require them to pivot and display all the separated rows (by warehouse) to display in a singular row () by stock code. below is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(IMB.StockCode) StockCode
, IM.Description
, IM.CostUom
, IM.StockOnHold
, IV.LastCostEntered
, IV.UnitCost
, IV.Warehouse
, IM.Supplier
, IM.StockUom
, IM.AlternateUom
, IM.OtherUom
FROM InvMultBin IMB
INNER JOIN InvMaster IM ON IMB.StockCode=IM.StockCode
    INNER JOIN InvWarehouse IV ON IV.StockCode=IMB.StockCode
WHERE IMB.LastIssueDate >GETDATE()-YEAR(1) AND IV.Warehouse LIKE '%'
ORDER BY StockCode
```

then this is what it produces (first 15 rows at least):

```
StockCode   Description CostUom StockOnHold LastCostEntered UnitCost    Warehouse   Supplier    StockUom    AlternateUom    OtherUom
AF0006  No 8 Fomopak                    125     38.06750    38.06750     C1 0001255 125 500 125
AF0006  No 8 Fomopak                    125     39.27750    39.27750    P1  0001255 125 500 125
AF0006  No 8 Fomopak                    125     38.06000    38.06000    D1  0001255 125 500 125
AF0006  No 8 Fomopak                    125     38.06750    38.06750    J1  0001255 125 500 125
AF0006  No 8 Fomopak                    125     39.27750    39.13500    G1  0001255 125 500 125
AF0009  No 34 Fomopak                   125     56.92250    79.34897    G1  0001255 125 125 125
AF0009  No 34 Fomopak                   125     56.38000    56.75328    C1  0001255 125 125 125
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     61.42000    60.37000    B1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     61.41000    60.46750    D1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     59.52000    59.52000    C1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     61.41750    60.06794    P1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     61.41750    61.41750    G1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     53.62000    53.62000    T1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0011  No 65S Fomopak                  375     61.41000    61.41000    J1  0001255 375 375 375
AF0012  No 69 Fomopak                   250     140.76500   140.76500   G1  0001255 250 250 250
```

I need it do display as follows by column:

```
StockCode
Description
CostUom
StockOnHold
LastCostEntered
UnitCost
B1
C1
D1
G1
J1
M1
P1
T1
Supplier
StockUom
AlternateUom
OtherUom
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: From your example, it looks like you are trying to list all headers of your table except for 'Warehouse', where you would like to list distinct values of that column. Is that correct?

Comment: not entirely. the list provided is a reference of the outcome columns needed. Each row of the original outcome (like StockCode AF0006) should be listed as a single row.

Comment: on a second note, the `LastCostEntered` column should also be split like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need to UNPIVOT the columns into rows. As another poster pointed out, without having sample data or knowing more about the DB layout, providing a specific solution that works 'out of the box' is a little difficult. With that said, here is a stab at how using UNPIVOT may look in your final implementation.

```
    WITH UNPIV_CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(IMB.StockCode) StockCode
    , IM.Description
    , IM.CostUom
    , IM.StockOnHold
    , IV.LastCostEntered
    , IV.UnitCost
    , IV.Warehouse
    , IM.Supplier
    , IM.StockUom
    , IM.AlternateUom
    , IM.OtherUom
    FROM InvMultBin IMB
    INNER JOIN InvMaster IM ON IMB.StockCode=IM.StockCode
        INNER JOIN InvWarehouse IV ON IV.StockCode=IMB.StockCode
    WHERE IMB.LastIssueDate >GETDATE()-YEAR(1) AND IV.Warehouse LIKE '%'
    )
-- Start of UNPIVOT
    SELECT u.StockCode, u.Column_Names, u.Column_Values
    FROM UNPIV_CTE UnP
-- Two new columns created with self explanatory names.  
    UNPIVOT ( Column_Values FOR Column_Names IN ([Description]
    , CostUom
    , StockOnHold
    , LastCostEntered
    , UnitCost
    , Warehouse
    , Supplier
    , StockUom
    , AlternateUom
    , OtherUom )
    ) u
    ORDER BY u.StockCode DESC
    ;
```

It uses your exact query, but wrapped up in a CTE to make it easier to see how the UNPIVOT works. You may want to tweak this script a bit to meet your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, thanks. i have little experience with CTE's combined with Pivots and Unpivots and this demonstrates it perfectly

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help! I noticed that Warehouse is treated a little differently. You may want to try commenting it out of the `UNPIVOT` and adding it to the final `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Noticed it too. leaving it it could cause it to list all rows again but with the unpivoted columns as well.